# Variations in number of features using ORB Algorithm

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am new to ML and working on a project. The project problem is basically a binary class classification problem and I am working on images (COVID, Normal Prediction). I have stuck into this problem that I am using ORB feature descriptor and detector to get features from images. The issue is that I am getting unbalanced feature vectors which I cant use with Traditional ML algorithms like SVM, KNN, etc.
(CODE BELOW HAS EXCLUDED Normal Images here for ease)
This is my code

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2
import os

print (cv2.__version__)

path1 = 'D:\\Semester 6\\ML\\Image Classification\\Testing\\Train\\COVID'
path2 = 'D:\\Semester 6\\ML\\Image Classification\\Testing\\Train\\Normal'
images1 = []
images2 = []
myListC = os.listdir(path1)
myListN = os.listdir(path2)

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

for clC in myListC:
    imgCur1 = cv2.imread(f'{path1}/{clC}', 0)
    imgCur1 = cv2.resize(imgCur1, (200,200))
    print(len(imgCur1))
    images1.append(imgCur1)

desListC = []
for img in images1:
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    e, z = des1.shape
    des1 = des1.reshape(e*z)
    print(des1.shape)
    desListC.append(des1)

desList = np.array(desList) 

X = []
y = []

for i in range(len(desList)):
     X.append(desList[i][:-1])

for i in range(len(desList)):
     y.append(desList[i][-1:])

X = np.array(X) 
y = np.array(y) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

OUTPUTS:

[image: Shape of Descriptor]

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: "The issue is that I am getting unbalanced feature vectors which I cant use with Traditional ML" -- that's expected. ORB features are also binary bitstrings, not feasible with a DecisionTree, which probably uses L2 distance. you'll have to change our design here. IF you want to use features2d descriptors, you need float ones (like SIFT or SURF) and you probably need either "dense" sampling (grid, not kepoints) or  BagOfWords clustering to get equal-length, balanced features for the classification

Comment: ORB is not a great starting point. You can have  a better start with https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.hog

Comment: Thank you for Your comments. I have found a way to do that though it's not that good I have sliced the descriptors to the lowest number of features vector (the one that has the lowest shape) for everyone and hence I got equal-sized vectors there is another way and that is to fill with 0s to make the maximum feature vector(the one that has the maximum shape) in this case info won't loose much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I have found a couple of ways to co-op with it and these are:

1. To Slice every time I get a descriptor vector to the lowest shaped array
2. To us fillna and insert 0s to make the shape the same as the largest shaped array

By using the above methods one can compare both the methods and check which one fits the best so consider that one.

I have sliced every time I get a descriptor array

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

desListC = []
for img in x_train:
    kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    e, z = des.shape
    des = des.reshape(e*z)
    des = des[:64]
    desListC.append(des)
    
desListC = np.array(desListC)
x_train = desListC
```

There are some other ways as well like using blobs but the above one seems the best and fast.

Comment: again, you cannot use ORB features with a tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: I have used it and got the predicitons. ORB giving me array of numbers (Features)

Comment: do you **understand**, what ORB features are ? (and why you're totally on the wrong bus, even if it "seems" to work for you, atm. ?)

Comment: I have to submit my university project soon and I don't know why it's not giving me binary feature vectors. It uses BRIEF and that should give binary features.
Its giving me resultant descriptors as:
[[ 82  32  80 ...   8  98 128]
 [120  32  16 ... 136  66   3]
 [114  32  84 ...   8  83 128]
 ...